# How to simplify a validation check in "modern" python?

Tags: python

I am refactoring a "big" python class and I am trying to reduce repetition to make the code shorter and more readable.

```
if 'name' not in item:
    error = "no name key found in definition"
    return False, error, {}

if 'type' not in item:
    error = "no type key found in definition"
    return False, error, {}

if 'of' not in item:
    error = "no of key found in definition"
    return False, error, {}
```

Basically, I have converted my json input to dictionary and I am looking if same specific elements exist. In case a key does not appear in the input, the function returns False, an information message and an empty dictionary.

I can make a class method that takes the argument name and evaluate the existence, however I was wondering if there is a better way to do it in python 3.x

Comment: From this snippet all we can suggest is looping over the keys, we don't know what context this operates in or how much change you can actually make (e.g. can you change the fundamental design to use errors instead of returning tuples of presumably `(success, error_message, value)`?)

Comment: what is the problem with returning multiple values?

Comment: I cannot understand the downvotes. Even a simple question, well asked, remains a question.

Comment: 1. Nothing *as such*, but you seem to be using it for error control; but this isn't Go or a Node callback, you don't need to fill the layer above with e.g. `if not success:`. By again, without more context it's hard to say. 2. Why do you think this is well asked? Given what you've accepted it seems your question was really just about deduplicating trivial repetition with loops, in which case there are many duplicates.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I disagree and think a enough context has been provided in this particular case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I don't think it matters or is that important.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the usage of the tuple is out of scope. better means ' I am trying to reduce repetition'.  It is stated in the first line of the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree, **but** the solution is to provide a duplicate and close the question. Not starting a discussion that would belong on meta (and be closed as a duplicate there ;)).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did look for a dupe, but couldn't find one directly and didn't feel like spending a lot of time on it. But then, I didn't start discussing it neither ;-).

Comment: @jonrsharpe ending your discussion. At least that was the plan. However, you're not behaving according to my plan. See, it's all your fault ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this bit of code can be refactored to avoid repetition like this:

```
for part in ['name', 'type', 'of']:
    if part not in item:
        error = "no {} key found in definition".format(part)
        return False, error, {}
```

Not sure I can add much about best practices for validation in general in Python. I think it's pretty much done as needed using general purpose constructs like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop and string interpolation to reduce that to:

```
for key in ('name', 'type', 'of'):
    if key not in item:
        error = "no {} key found in definition".format(key)
        return False, error, {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are explicitly naming the missing key instead of doing something like

```
if "name" not in item or "type" not in item or "of" not in item:
    return False, "key missing in definition", {}
```

you should probably do it right and iterate through all of them. Adapting Dan D.'s solution:

```
error = ''
for key in ('name', 'type', 'of'):
    if key not in item:
        error += " no {} key found in definition".format(key)
if error != ''
    return False, error, {}
```

Or something similar. What if name and type are missing? You would only see the missing name in your example.